# Eclipse does not put servlet mappings into web.xml

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, web.xml

I have added new servlet to eclipse project with it's wizard and wizard also asked for servlet mapping. Now I can see this mapping in project explorer tree under Deployment descriptor - Servlet mappings, but web.xml does not contain this mapping.

Is this an eclipse bug or mappings are stored somewhere else nowadays?

Mappings do work.

Eclipse is Indigo.
Tomcat is 7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mappings are set with `@WebServlet` annotation now.